# Centos 7 and OpenVPN: how make them friends?

Tags: centos, openvpn, selinux, centos7

I'm trying to install OpenVPN server on Centos 7 and faced with next problem:

```
[root@msk ~]# /etc/init.d/openvpn start
Starting openvpn (via systemctl):                          [  OK  ]
[root@msk ~]# ps aux | grep openvpn
root      5639  0.0  0.0 112640   980 pts/6    S+   12:54   0:00 grep --color=auto openvpn
[root@msk ~]# service openvpn start
Starting openvpn (via systemctl):                          [  OK  ]
[root@msk ~]# ps aux | grep openvpn
root      5657  0.0  0.0 112640   980 pts/6    S+   12:54   0:00 grep --color=auto openvpn
[root@msk ~]#
```

As you can see - nothing happens.

But if i'll try to start it with single command: `openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/openvpn.pid --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --cd /etc/openvpn` it works nice.

I think problem is `selinux`. And I don't want to disable it at all.

Could you point me where is error?

Comment: If you think the problem is SELinux,have you looked in the audit log for relevant messages ?

Comment: yes. and i made this: `cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep openvpn | grep denied | audit2allow -M myopenvpn; semodule -i myopenvpn.pp`

Comment: You may need to put SElinux temporarily into Permissive mode so that you can gather all of the relevant log entries but you should also reinstall using the native openvpn package.

Comment: A little trick; a `grep -v grep` could filter out the `grep` from your `ps uxa` output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CentOS 7 uses [systemd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.service.5.html) to control system service daemons. That you are using init scripts suggests that you have installed your openvpn without using a package manger ( the openvpn-2.3.2-4.el7 rpm doesn't contain init scripts)

I think at this point, rather than trying to debug and use init scripts it would be better to remove your current installation and then install and configure the natively supported package. Something like

```
yum install openvpn
systemctl enable openvpn@service.service

systemctl start openvpn@server.service
systemctl status -l openvpn@server.service
```

Notice the use of openvpn@server, this relates to the /etc/openvpn configuration file which in this case would be expected to be /etc/openvpn/server.conf. If for example you had openvpn listening on port 443 you could

```
systemctl enable openvpn@port443.service
```

and you would complement that with a `/etc/openvpn/port443.conf`.

Comment: thanks!!! so fast)

but i noticed different version of vpn server:
`
    [root@msk local]# yum install openvpn
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.logol.ru
     * extras: mirror.logol.ru
     * rpmforge: mirror.awanti.com
     * updates: mirror.yandex.ru
    Package matching openvpn-2.2.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
    Nothing to do`

what repo do you recommend to use?

Comment: I don't know how you got an el6 rpm on your el7 system. Did you upgrade el6 to el7 ? is it really an el7 system ?

Comment: @lain yes, it seems so:
`[root@msk /]# uname -a
Linux host.msk.ru 3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 6 21:12:36 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. And no, it was installed from image. Without upgrades

Comment: Thank you!!! 

i fixed it by fully reinstalling openvpn from scratch. 
and i found how old version came to system.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've installed EPEL openvpn. I have a valid (tested) config file in /etc/openvpn/client.conf. But trying to start the service via systemd invariably produces "  Process: 16437 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/%i.pid --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
...Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: client.conf" even though the command appears correct.